# Integrating Spring SAML as SP and SimpleSAMLphp as IdP (HoK profile)

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml, simplesamlphp, saml-2.0

I am trying to get HoK profile work with Spring SAML as the SP and SimpleSAMLphp as the IdP.

The SP gets the client certificate and then sends the following authentication request to the IdP without problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sp.com/saml/HoKSSO"
    Destination="https://localhost:8443/simplesaml/saml2   /idp/SSOService.php"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="a5ba2704fgc63887442i9i1298904fh"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2015-10-04T11:26:47.393Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sp.com/saml/metadata</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

In response, the IdP requests for the client certificate during TLS handshake and then gets his username/password and authenticates him successfully. It sends the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response Destination="https://sp.com/saml/HoKSSO"
    ID="_94c3201b7ae79d95f8ef289705c406bd61b8ed81f1"
    InResponseTo="a5ba2704fgc63887442i9i1298904fh"
    IssueInstant="2015-10-04T11:26:47Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>https://localhost:8443/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID="_b703fd12c6692e7a5d431d539888fcb01171a41f92"
        IssueInstant="2015-10-04T11:26:47Z" Version="2.0"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <saml:Issuer>https://localhost:8443/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID
                Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" SPNameQualifier="https://sp.com/saml/metadata">b9bdc06e4c25f5a464c6d5586394d6922031bd1d</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:holder-of-key">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData
                    InResponseTo="a5ba2704fgc63887442i9i1298904fh"
                    NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-04T11:31:47Z" Recipient="https://sp.com/saml/HoKSSO">
                    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </saml:SubjectConfirmationData>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-10-04T11:26:17Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-04T11:31:47Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://sp.com/saml/metadata</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-10-04T11:08:06Z"
            SessionIndex="_2e1ddd44e4b2215a074312dc7a1e31865dd940f49f" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2015-10-04T19:26:47Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">student</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">member</saml:AttributeValue>
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">student</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Everything seems OK but Spring SAML throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:95)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:62)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:84)
... 43 more
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Assertion invalidated by subject confirmation - can't be confirmed by holder-of-key method
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl.verifySubject(WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:296)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
... 44 more
```

Spring SAML debugging logs here:

```
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Evaluating security policy of type 'org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BasicSecurityPolicy' for decoded message
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Evaluating simple signature rule of type: org.opensaml.saml2.binding.security.SAML2HTTPPostSimpleSignRule
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - HTTP request was not signed via simple signature mechanism, skipping
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] INFO    - SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Successfully decoded message.
8532 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Checking SAML message intended destination endpoint against receiver endpoint
8533 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Intended message destination endpoint: https://cmks.irannid.ir/saml/HoKSSO
8533 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Actual message receiver endpoint: https://cmks.irannid.ir/saml/HoKSSO
8533 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - SAML message intended destination endpoint matched recipient endpoint
8533 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Found endpoint org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.impl.AssertionConsumerServiceImpl@38620660 for request URL https://cmks.irannid.ir/saml/HoKSSO based on location attribute in metadata
8534 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider
8534 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Verifying issuer of the Response
8535 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Processing Holder-of-Key subject confirmation
8535 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - HoK SubjectConfirmation invalidated by confirmation data not being of KeyInformationDataType type
8535 [http-nio-443-exec-9] DEBUG   - Validation of authentication statement in assertion failed, skipping
```

The error is: **HoK SubjectConfirmation invalidated by confirmation data not being of KeyInformationDataType type**. It seems that Spring SAML could not find KeyInfo in the response!!

Can anybody help me resolve this problem?

Thank you

**Edit:**

By comparing with sample HoK SSO responses, it sees that SimpleSAMLphp has not added **xsi:type="saml:KeyInfoConfirmationDataType"** to the SubjectConfirmationData tag. Can it be the reason of the above exception?

Is it a mandatory attribute for the SubjectConfirmationData tag in SAML2.0 HoK profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

SimpleSAMLphp does not add xsi:type="saml:KeyInfoConfirmationDataType" to the "SubjectConfirmationData" tag, because the standard does not mandate it:

```
329  3.1 Holder of Key
330  URI: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:holder-of-key
331  One or more <ds:KeyInfo> elements MUST be present within the <SubjectConfirmationData>
332  element. An xsi:type attribute MAY be present in the <SubjectConfirmationData> element and, if
333  present, MUST be set to saml:KeyInfoConfirmationDataType (the namespace prefix is arbitrary but
334  must reference the SAML assertion namespace).
```

I changed the simplesamlphp code and added the missing attribute manually. (I'm still not sure whether I added in the right place or not but it works by now!)
But the new question is who must resolve this problem? Spring SAML or simpleSAMLphp?

By this change, Spring SAML detects that SubjectConfirmationData tag contains one or more  elements, then it finds the client certificate embedded in the response and tries to compare it with the one received during TLS client authentication.

Although the two certificates are identical, Spring SAML says they don't match, since one of them has break lines and the other does not.

My only remaining my question is:

which approach is compatible with standard? adding break lines in base64-encoded certificates or removing them or even comparing with and without break lines?

Comment: hello ,i have exactly that problem and i got that exception either, can you add your changes(codes) to simplesamlphp here?I don't know how can i add the missing attribute manually?!